# Java URL: invalid query

Tags: java, url

my program crashes by formatting a wrong URL query.
I use following method to parse it

```
public GetMethod get(String uri) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        ProtocolSocketFactory factory = getFactory(url.getProtocol());
        Protocol protocol = new Protocol(url.getProtocol(), factory, url.getPort());
        httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), protocol);

        GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url.getPath() + "?" + url.getQuery());
        httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);

        return getMethod;
    }
```

The uri can contain for example the following:

> http://localhost:8180/Logi-Reports/rdTemplate/rdGetSecureKey.aspx?Username=demo&Rights=AC%2CAD%2CAR%2CAS%2CAdvanced%2CBP%2CBPA%2CBPS%2CDashboard%2CID%2CLUA%2CMA%2CME-IN%2CME-OUT%2CMEA-IN%2CMEA-OUT%2CMES-IN%2CMES-OUT%2CMPC%2CREP%2CSA%2CSF%2CUA%2CUP%2CUPA%2CUPS&DataOwner=1,10,7,3,8,12,15,16,4,5,14,9,11,17,6,13,2&DateFormat=dd/MM/yyyy&DateTimeFormat=dd/MM/yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss&NumberFormat=#,##0.##:.,&UserCurrency=EUR&ClientBrowserAddress=0.0.0.0

When I get into the constructor of the method and I do url.getQuery(), I receive the following:

> Username=demo&Rights=AC%2CAD%2CAR%2CAS%2CAdvanced%2CBP%2CBPA%2CBPS%2CDashboard%2CID%2CLUA%2CMA%2CME-IN%2CME-OUT%2CMEA-IN%2CMEA-OUT%2CMES-IN%2CMES-OUT%2CMPC%2CREP%2CSA%2CSF%2CUA%2CUP%2CUPA%2CUPS&DataOwner=1,10,7,3,8,12,15,16,4,5,14,9,11,17,6,13,2&DateFormat=dd/MM/yyyy&DateTimeFormat=dd/MM/yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss&NumberFormat=

After my NumberFormat, everything is dropped. How does this come?

**Update**

I replaced all # by %23, now I have following method:

```
public GetMethod get(String uri) throws IOException {
        uri = uri.replaceAll("#","%23");
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        ProtocolSocketFactory factory = getFactory(url.getProtocol());
        Protocol protocol = new Protocol(url.getProtocol(), factory, url.getPort());
        httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), protocol);

        GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url.getPath() + "?" + url.getQuery());
        httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);

        return getMethod;
    }
```

And when I encode my url I have following result:

> 14:09:22,027 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/trax].[default]]
>   (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   default threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   uri
>   '/Trax-Logi-Reports/rdTemplate/rdGetSecureKey.aspx?Username=demo&Rights=AC%2CAD%2CAR%2CAS%2CAdvanced%2CBP%2CBPA%2CBPS%2CDashboard%2CID%2CLUA%2CMA%2CME-IN%2CME-OUT%2CMEA-IN%2CMEA-OUT%2CMES-IN%2CMES-OUT%2CMPC%2CREP%2CSA%2CSF%2CUA%2CUP%2CUPA%2CUPS&DataOwner=1,10,7,3,8,12,15,16,4,5,14,9,11,17,6,13,2&DateFormat=dd/MM/yyyy&DateTimeFormat=dd/MM/yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss&NumberFormat=%23,%23%230.%23%23&UserCurrency=EUR&ClientBrowserAddress=0.0.0.0':
>   Invalid query

What is wrong? I don't see anything.

Comment: use URLEncoder.encode to encode the plain text string

Comment: for new URL("/Trax-Logi-Reports") you'll get MalformedURLException as no protocol is specified. Please describe in more detail your control flow. Which part is called by what URL?

Comment: You appear to have a space between yyyy and HH in DateTimeFormat. **Space is not allowed** in URL/URI. Encode it as %20 (like any other disallowed char) or + (plus sign; special case for space *in query* aka parameters) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type ..

Comment: I encoded it as well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that & and # are special characters with some meaning in URLs:

- `&` is used to **separate parameters** from each other
- `#` denotes a **local link** into a file - this will not be passed into the server but will be evaluated client-side (by the browser normally).

Encode your `#` to `%23` and you'll see more.

You should also consider setting your params one by one using the appropriate calls:

```
 GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url.getPath());
 getMethod.getParams().setParameter("Username", "demo");
```

and so on

Comment: Ok, but now I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri '/Logi-Reports/rdTemplate/rdGetSecureKey.aspx?Username=demo&Rights=AC%2CAD%2CAR%2CAS%2CAdvanced%2CBP%2CBPA%2CBPS%2CDashboard%2CID%2CLUA%2CMA%2CME-IN%2CME-OUT%2CMEA-IN%2CMEA-OUT%2CMES-IN%2CMES-OUT%2CMPC%2CREP%2CSA%2CSF%2CUA%2CUP%2CUPA%2CUPS&DataOwner=1,10,7,3,8,12,15,16,4,5,14,9,11,17,6,13,2&DateFormat=dd/MM/yyyy&DateTimeFormat=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss&NumberFormat=%23,%23%230.%23%23&UserCurrency=EUR&ClientBrowserAddress=0.0.0.0': Invalid query

Comment: where do you get that? What do you see in server?